How to stop logging errors from the JS AWS SDK (S3)
I’m using s3.getObject within the S3 AWS SDK in JavaScript. This S3 object may legitimately not exist, and I’m handling that condition fine in my application.
However, in Datadog I’m seeing so many spam logs of the NoSuchKey error. Because I’m not logging that myself, and I’m not leaving the error  uncaught, I’m guessing it’s the SDK itself that is logging this.
I’ve tried replacing the logger inside S3 with just a null logger, however these NoSuchKey errors are still somehow making it to Datadog.
I’m using the following code which I thought would work:
const nullLogger = {
  log: () => {},
  write: () => {},
  error: () => {},
  warn: () => {},
  debug: () => {}
};

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  logger: nullLogger,
  region
});

The getObject usage is within a try/catch, and the error is being correctly handled.

The AWS SDK normally doesn't log anything. Can you show the exact error? Are the errors also in the Cloudwatch logs of the Lambda? How does it get into Datadog? Maybe the Datadog tracing library is detecting the "error" and logs it...?

I'm experiencing the same issue...

@SAE nope no logs or errors in Cloudwatch for it, getObject is wrapped in a try/catch because we want to ignore this error in this scenario.

@SAE Logs get to DD via dd-trace NPM library, which is why I’m hoping I can just get the package itself to stop logging.
